# Removing the file name spaces of a browsed file or the input file

Tags: php, spaces

We're working on a converter but How can we remove the file name of the browsed file, **not the string typed by the users**

Comment: can you add an example of "what do you have" and "what do you expect" ?

Comment: for example I have here a file named Raw video.avi, my program cannot fetch the file with spaces, so how can I automatically remove spaces from the inputted files. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This should work for what ever your asking..?

```
//get the filename
$files = array_values($_FILES);
$filename = isset($files['name'])?$files['name']:$files[0]['name'];

//replace space
echo str_replace(' ','',$filename);
```

Comment: Thanks for the response but where can I put the code? before or after the process?